# How to Parse through nested JSON using Angular and get needed fields dynamically?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a JSON generated from which I need to access various fields like message-name as example in the json. I am unable to iterate and fetch the data from the json.

```
"playlist": [
      {
        "pick-policy": "sequence",
        "item-list": {
          "script": [
            {
              "max-expected-duration": "00:00:00.00",
              "message-identifier": "50160",
              "message-name": "Visa - WF - Denver - Module - Campus Buildings",
              "ingredients": {
                "text": [
                  {
                    "_name": "filter"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "title",
                    "__text": "Campus Buildings"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "feature",
                    "__text": "map"
                  }
                ],
                "resource": {
                  "_name": "itemPlaylist",
                  "__text": "Visa - WF - Denver - Buildings"
                },
                "filename": {
                  "_name": "icon",
                  "__text": "Signet Holding/visa/icons/campus[50047518500].png"
                }
              },
              "metadata": {
                "string": [
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.ModifiedDate",
                    "__text": "2015-11-10T14:51:24-0600"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.OwnerWorkgroup",
                    "__text": "Denver"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.keywords"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.zip code"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.LocationType"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.OverrideName"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.Industry"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.SlideCount"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "_name": "apps/WayFinding_Module[50014673103].scb"
            },
            {
              "max-expected-duration": "00:00:00.00",
              "message-identifier": "50161",
              "message-name": "Visa - WF - Denver - Module - Conference",
              "ingredients": {
                "text": [
                  {
                    "_name": "title",
                    "__text": "Conference Rooms"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "filter",
                    "__text": "Conference"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "feature",
                    "__text": "list"
                  }
                ],
                "filename": {
                  "_name": "icon",
                  "__text": "Signet Holding/visa/icons/conference[50047520000].png"
                }
              },
              "metadata": {
                "string": [
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.ModifiedDate",
                    "__text": "2015-11-10T14:50:57-0600"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.OwnerWorkgroup",
                    "__text": "Denver"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.keywords"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.zip code"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.LocationType"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.OverrideName"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.Industry"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.SlideCount"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "_name": "apps/WayFinding_Module[50014673103].scb"
            },
            {
              "max-expected-duration": "00:00:00.00",
              "message-identifier": "50159",
              "message-name": "Visa - WF - Denver - Module - Hotelling",
              "ingredients": {
                "text": [
                  {
                    "_name": "filter",
                    "__text": "Hotelling"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "title",
                    "__text": "Hotelling Areas"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "feature",
                    "__text": "list"
                  }
                ],
                "filename": {
                  "_name": "icon",
                  "__text": "Signet Holding/visa/icons/hotel[50047521600].png"
                }
              },
              "metadata": {
                "string": [
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.ModifiedDate",
                    "__text": "2015-11-10T14:51:39-0600"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.OwnerWorkgroup",
                    "__text": "Denver"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.keywords"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.zip code"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.LocationType"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.OverrideName"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.Industry"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.SlideCount"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "_name": "apps/WayFinding_Module[50014673103].scb"
            },
            {
              "max-expected-duration": "00:00:00.00",
              "message-identifier": "50162",
              "message-name": "Visa - WF - Denver - Module - Huddle",
              "ingredients": {
                "text": [
                  {
                    "_name": "feature",
                    "__text": "list"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "filter",
                    "__text": "Huddle"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "title",
                    "__text": "Huddle Rooms"
                  }
                ],
                "filename": {
                  "_name": "icon",
                  "__text": "Signet Holding/visa/icons/conference[50047520000].png"
                }
              },
              "metadata": {
                "string": [
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.ModifiedDate",
                    "__text": "2015-11-10T14:51:11-0600"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.OwnerWorkgroup",
                    "__text": "Denver"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.keywords"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.zip code"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.LocationType"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.OverrideName"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.Industry"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.SlideCount"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "_name": "apps/WayFinding_Module[50014673103].scb"
            },
            {
              "max-expected-duration": "00:00:00.00",
              "message-identifier": "50158",
              "message-name": "Visa - WF - Denver - Module - Shuttle",
              "ingredients": {
                "text": [
                  {
                    "_name": "title",
                    "__text": "Shuttle Schedule"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "feature",
                    "__text": "shuttle"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "filter"
                  }
                ],
                "filename": {
                  "_name": "icon",
                  "__text": "Signet Holding/visa/icons/shuttle[50047524600].png"
                }
              },
              "metadata": {
                "string": [
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.ModifiedDate",
                    "__text": "2015-11-10T14:51:54-0600"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.OwnerWorkgroup",
                    "__text": "Denver"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.keywords"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.zip code"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.LocationType"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.OverrideName"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.Industry"
                  },
                  {
                    "_name": "MediaItem.SlideCount"
                  }
                ]
              },
```

I am no creating a factory for it using angular. But I am lost after that:

```
var jsonPlan = {'modules':[]};

//  console.log(playlists);
    angular.forEach(playlists, function(playlist, key) {
//      console.log(playlist._name);
        if(playlist._name == modulePlaylistName){
            angular.forEach(playlist['item-list'].content, function(module, key2) {
                var tempModule = {};
                angular.forEach(module.ingredients, function(ingredient, key3) {
                    if(key3 == "resource"){
                        angular.forEach(playlists, function(playlist, key4) {
                            if(playlist._name == ingredient.__text){

                                console.log("found item 'Buildings' playlist");
                                console.log("need to go further down the rabbit hole.......");


                            } 
                        });
                    } else if(ingredient._name === undefined){
                        angular.forEach(ingredient, function(ingredientSub, key4) {
                            tempModule[ingredientSub._name] = ingredientSub.__text;
                        });
                    } else {
                        tempModule[ingredient._name] = ingredient.__text;
                    }
                });

                jsonPlan['modules'].push(tempModule);

            });
        }
    });
```

Please help the way to get specific data from it dynamically.

Comment: Recursion is your friend

Comment: what does "lost after that" mean, exactly?  How can you expect us to tell you what you need to do when you can't clearly explain what it is you really need?

Comment: Hi @Claies I know what I need. I need to go through the innermost message-name and filters from the jason. I am able to reach couple of levels inside till 'ingredients'. But after that I am not able to go through more

Comment: what are all the `forEach` functions in your code trying to do? are you trying to extract pieces of this data and push it into another structure of some sort?

Comment: your comment doesn't really clarify your issue at all;  what does "I am not able to go through more" mean?  and what is the *result* you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to extract pieces of data and push it in another data structure. Another object.